# difference between array and wrapped list?

Tags: jquery

What is the difference in jquery between array & wrraped list?

I noticed in firebug, there is a dropdown on the 2nd variable t.

```
var t = $('li').toArray(); 
        alert(t);


                 t = $('li'); 
        alert(t);

        })
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery object has extra properties that are, well...jQuery object properties.  The prototype (the `$.fn` shortcut, same thing), giving you [all those chainable functions](http://api.jquery.com/).

To be clear, jQuery objects are not arrays, they *behave* like arrays (the [`.length` property](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/core.js#L198), [`.slice()` method](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/core.js#L288), etc).  For a list of those extra properties (and the array emulating ones), [look here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/core.js#L192) in the source.